# adding description text to a each radio button in my radiobutton list

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Trying to add some descriptive text to my radio buttons in my radio button list.

for some reason the column is SO narrow that the radio button stretches down very long.

Is there a way I can format this to look nice?

Should I be adding the text to radiobutton.text or somewhere else?

Comment: Probably a CSS problem - gonna need some code before we can help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `RepeatLayout="Flow"`?